# Why my timeout configuration with RestTemplate doesn't work?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I need to change the timeout for a web service call.
Despite the configuration changes in several places, I go into timeout after 30 seconds.
Any ideas?

My configuration :

```java
private static final Duration CUSTOM_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMinutes(5);
...
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
              .setSocketTimeout(300000)
              .setConnectTimeout(300000)
              .setConnectionRequestTimeout(300000)
              .build();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder
              .create()
              .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
              .build();

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
              .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
              .errorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler())
              .setConnectTimeout(CUSTOM_TIMEOUT)
              .setReadTimeout(CUSTOM_TIMEOUT)
              .build();

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(client);
factory.setConnectTimeout(300000);
factory.setReadTimeout(300000);
factory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(300000);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

Thanks

Comment: What specific error are you getting after 30 seconds? Are you getting an exception? What specific exception?

Comment: What should be the expected period you want a timeout to be happen? Please pass exception information as well. And BTW your config is redundent.

Comment: I just have a Gateway TimeOut.
I just want to increase the timeout but it doesn't work, it stays at 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

A [gateway timeout (504)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/504) indicates that the server you are talking to has reached *its own* timeout waiting for another service.

The timeout of that server seems to be 30 seconds, and you simply cannot configure it from your code, no matter what library you use.